# How many triplets $\left(m,n,p\right)$ where $p$ is prime satisfy $m^2-3mn+p^2n^2=12p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many triplets $\left(m,n,p\right)$ where $p$ is prime satisfy $m^2-3mn+p^2n^2=12p$?

I've tried taking both sides of the equation modulo 2, 3, and 4, but it hasn't gotten me very far.

Comment: Any conditions that m,n are integers?

Comment: Well, they're called $m$ and $n$ so they're probably integers. It'd be weird if they were $x$ and $y$

Comment: Well, because if they were not integers, then there would easily be infinite solutions.

Comment: The question **is** tagged as belonging to *(elementary-)number-theory* so there is a strong inference that the variables would be constrained to integers. Don't how much weight we give to that kiind of thinking here though? It is not entirely reliable, because there are some users who think that number theory tag is a "perfect" fit to a theoretical sounding question that has something to do with numbers.

Comment: I agree that it should be given in what set we're working. It's still quite unclear if this is in $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N_0}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$. However, given that $p$ is prime and just the typical number-theory equation and style, it's clear that they are integers. This user probably realizes quite well that his tags are appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

In this answer I assume $n,m,p\in\mathbb{N}$, then generalize to $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and then to $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Let's assume $p\neq 3$. We look at the equality $\mod 3$ to get $$m^2+n^2p^2\equiv 0\mod 3$$
Since squares are always $0$ or $1\mod 3$, we know both $m^2$ and $n^2p^2$ are $0\mod 3$ (since if one is $1$, then the other must be $2$ - impossible). So, $m$ and $n$ are both divisible by $3$. Now write $m=3m'$ and $n=3n'$ to get
$$9m'^2-27m'n'+9n'^2p^2=12p$$
which results in
$$3m'^2-9m'n'+3n'^2p^2=4p$$
and the left-hand side is divisible by $3$, thus, so is the left - we get that $3|4p$ and so $3|p$, which means $p=3$. This is in contradicting with what we assumed, so our assumption must be wrong - we now know $p=3$.

---

The equation becomes $m^2-3mn+9n^2=36$. Obviously, $m$ is divisble by $3$, so now write $3m_0=m$ so that we get
$$m_0^2-m_0n+n^2=4$$
but with AM-GM we see $$\frac{4+m_0n}{2}=\frac{m_0^2+n^2}{2}\geq m_0n$$
Thus, $4\geq m_0n$. This results in finitely many options, which are $$(m_0,n)\in\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(4,1)\}$$
Just trying them all gives $(m_0,n)=(2,2)$, which translates to a triplet $(m,n,p)=(3m_0,n,p)=(6,2,3)$. So the answer is $1$. One such triplet exists.

---

**Generalization to $\mathbb{N}_0$.**

If we allow $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, and we want $m_0^2-m_0n+n^2=4$, then set (without loss of generality) $m_0=0$, to get $n^2=4$ so $n=2$. We get two more triplets $(m,n,p)=(0,2,3)$ and $(m,n,p)=(6,0,3)$, which makes the answer here $3$. There are three triplets satisfying given condition.

---

**Generalization to $\mathbb{Z}$.**

We see that the arguments above to show that $p=3$ still work. We get to the point where we need to solve $$m_1^2+m_1n_1+n_1^2=4$$ (since changing the sign of $m_0$ or $n$ will only change the sign of $m_0n$ and not of $m_0^2$ and $n^2$. We get new solutions for changing the sign of both $m_0$ and $n$ in our old solutions. Now we change sign of only one of the two, and we arrive at the above equation). Note that we'll need to solve this for *positive* integers $m_1,n_1$ again. If one of $m_1,n_1$ is greater than or equal to $2$, then there are no solutions, since then one term is at least $4$, and the other two terms are both at least $1$, but $6>4$. Thus, $m_1=n_1=1$, and this is no solution. We get that all solutions are:
$$(m,n,p)\in\{(6,2,3),(0,2,3),(6,0,3),(-6,-2,3),(0,-2,3),(-6,0,3)\}$$
so there are $6$ solutions for this.